# ¿Existe una orden similar a sum( ) para restar?

Tags: r, matemáticas, estadística

Es una pregunta sencilla.
Existe sum para sumar pero, ¿hay un equivalente para restar?

No aparece por ninguna parte...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sum(num*-1) no restaria todos?

Comment: No se puede porque la resta está definida solo para un par de números, puedes restar dos números: `a-b` pero no puedes restar (sacar la diferencia) tres números `a-b-c`.
Lo que sí puedes hacer es una suma cambiando los signos: `(+1)(a)+(-1)b+(1)c`

Answer (score 2):

**Respuesta:** No existe una *función* con la forma similar a `sum()` que defina a la resta o sustracción aritmética. La razón es porque la función `sum()` no está definida dentro del grupo de funciones de aritmética básica de R sino dentro del grupo de funciones de estadísticas de resumen, llamado `Summary`. Otras funciones definidas dentro de este grupo son `min()`, `max()`, `range()`, etc. Esta información viene incluída en la página de ayuda de las funciones genéricas de S4 (S es el lenguaje que antecedió a R), consultable como: `?Summary`.

Por otro lado, las operaciones aritméticas básicas en R están definidas con los operadores *binarios*: `+`,`-`,`/`,`*`. "Binario" aquí no se refiere al sistema de numeración de ceros y unos, sino a que los operadores aritméticos necesitarán dos *operandos* (o sea, valores) para devolver un resultado. Así, la suma  (`+`), la resta (`-`) y el resto de operaciones aritméticas están definidas dentro de otro grupo de funciones básicas, llamado  `Arith`. Esta información viene también en la página de ayuda de las funciones genéricas de S4, consultable como: `?Arith`.

Sin embargo, existe una manera simple de utilizar a los operadores aritméticos en la forma funcional, como si existiera una función `resta()` o `multiplicación()`. La forma de hacerlo es poner entre comillas simples (`''`) o dobles (`""`) (o incluso entre dos tildes invertidas: ``) el operador aritmérico que te interese utilizar en forma funcional, y luego abrir paréntesis. Por ejemplo, para la resta de `10 - 5` se puede escribir `"-"(10,5)`. Ambas operaciones devolverán `5`.

```
> 10 - 5
 5
> "-"(10, 5)
 5
> '-'(10, 5)
 5
> `-`(10, 5)
 5
```

No obstante, este método rápido tiene la desventaja de que sólo aceptará dos valores como argumentos. Es decir, si quisieras restar más de tres números al mismo tiempo te devolverá un error.

```
> `-`(10,5,2)
Error in `-`(10, 5, 2) : operator needs one or two arguments
```

Mi solución sería aprovechar que R permite construir tus propias funciones y hacer nuestra propia función de resta, de manera que funcione de la misma manera que la de suma, `sum()`, recibiendo un número indeterminado de números que se agregarán entre sí. Sin embargo, no me queda claro por tu pregunta si lo que deseas es que al primer elemento se le reste un número indefinido de elementos o si deseas que todos los elementos se resten entre sí. En cualquier caso, pongo las dos soluciones.

```
# Solución en donde se resta un número indeterminado de números
# al primer elemento
subtract <- function(...) {
  x <- c(...)
  x[1] + sum(vapply(x[2:length(x)], `-`, 1))
}
subtract(100, 50, 20, 30, 1)

[1] -1

# Solución en donde se restan todos los números
# entre sí
subtract <- function(...) {
  sum(vapply(c(...), `-`, 1))
}
subtract(100, 50, 20, 30, 1)

[1] -201
```

Answer (score 1):

No hay una función base en R para lo que entiendo sería una "cumulative lagged difference", algún que otro paquete la implementa, pero, de todas formas es bastante simple de construir:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 1)
head(x,1) - sum(tail(x,-1))

[1] -5
```

Tomamos el primer elemento del vector y lo restamos por la suma de los siguientes.

Otra forma útil es usar `Reduce()` para aplicar la resta ítem por ítem

```
Reduce(`-`, x)
```